# django + Nginx + Gunicorn - 404 for Static file when debug is false

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I dont know how nginx serves the static files

/etc/nginx/site-available/default :

```
upstream example.com {
  server unix:/home/www/example/env/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/www/example/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log //home/www/example/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
         alias /home/www/example/codeab/static/;
    }

    location /uploads/ {
        alias   /home/www/example/codeab/uploads/;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/www/example/env/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/www/example/templates/;
    }
    error_page 404 /401.html;
    location = /401.html {
        root /home/www/example/codeab/templates/;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Django setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =  (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_content/'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')
```

Also , I did collectstatic before DEBUG = False

It seems that nginx is not considering the above config file, as for 404 page it is not showing my custom 401.html page.

After editing the config, I linked it to site-enabled by

```
sudo ln -s /etc/site-available/default /etc/site-enabled/default
service nginx reload
sudo service nginx restart
```

Please help, or let me know If I am missing any things.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for posting such a detailed description of your problem, it helps a lot. A couple of things before we get down to the gist of your issue. If NGINX isn't seeing the config file, how is it returning 404 for your static files? The linking that you've stated at the end is right, but you need to check in `nginx.conf` if it's using `include /etc/site-enabled/*;` or `include /etc/site-enabled/*.conf;` If it's `*.conf`, you'll need to rename `default` to `default.conf`. Also, it's a bit strange that your `site-enabled` and `site-available` is sitting in `/etc/`

Comment: This is not by standard installation. On the case of your custom 4xx template: If NGINX is serving this, it needs to be a static HTML file. It can't have any templatetags in it as it's not being processed by Django. My suggestion would be to use Django's internal error templating for this. Lastly, about your static files, the config is right. The only thing I would change is `location ^~ /static/ {` so that NGINX knows that it must do a regex match and not straight string comparison.

Comment: Hi Keenan, thanks for quick response. I checked in my nginx.conf, it is `include /etc/site-enabled/*;` so file name is correct i.e. `default`

Comment: I also tried with `location ^~ /static/ {` but still nginx not serving static files.

Comment: Strange. What's the output when you run `python manage.py collectstatic`? i.e what directory is it collecting to?

Comment: 0 static files copied to '/home/www/example/codeab/static', 268 unmodified. as all static files are already copied.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the exact solution, but it started working on changing my gunicorn binding from `xxx.xxx.xx.xx:80` to `xxx.xx.xx.xx:8000` 
and editing config as -

```
location / {
        include proxy_params;
        #proxy_pass http://unix:/home/www/example/env/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000;
    }
```

I commented proxy_pass of sock file and added the new line as you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx serves static files from the dir defined in nginx config file under `location /static/` and redirects to custom 404 html page as defined in nginx config by you when it does not find such static resource in the defined dir.

Django displays the custom 404 html page when it does not find given url in any of the urls.py files of Django, provided you set `Debug = False` in settings.py and also point the `'TEMPLATES'-'DIRS'` setting to the dir containing your custom 404 html file as explained in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#template-loaders).

So, effectively the way nginx and Django displays the same 404 html page is different and independent of each other.

Answer (score -1):

Just change your the configuration in the nginx server block from

```
location /static/ {
         alias /home/www/example/codeab/static/;
    }
```

To

```
location /static/ {
         alias /home/www/example/codeab/static_content/;
    }
```

Reason, after the command `python manage.py collectstatic` has executed 
the static files are been placed inside of the static_content folder.

Comment: Tried, still not worked. after executing collectstatic, all files from static_content have been placed to static folder. Thats why you down voted.

Comment: so have you found a solution